# 16.04 retrofit for Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: 16.04, raspberrypi

The goal is to test Big Blue Button on the rPi4: currently supported on Ubuntu 16.04. I have successfully installed 19.10 on the rPi4 and smoke tested Jarret Buse's [18.04-rpi4 install procedure](https://www.linux.org/threads/ubuntu-18-04-64-bit-for-raspberry-pi-4.25258/):

1. Burn the [18.04 Ubuntu image](https://cloudkernels.net/ubuntu-18.04.2-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi4+kvm.img.xz) to target SD-card
2. **Merge** (do not overwrite any files) [Sakaki's boot & modules files](https://github.com/sakaki-/bcm2711-kernel/releases/download/4.19.66.20190816/bcm2711-kernel-4.19.66.20190816.tar.xz) files to their respective SD card partitions:

   - ‘boot’ folder merges into ‘system-boot’ partition
   - ‘modules’ folder and paste it into the ‘lib’ folder on the ‘writable’ partition
3. Edit the `config.txt` file:

   - comment out `` #\`total_mem=1024` ``
   - add the snippet immediately above section labeled `[all]`

SNIPPET:

```
[pi4]
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2
arm_64bit=1
enable_gic=1
kernel=kernel8-p4.img
```

## Questions

Reproducing these results with 16.04 would enable BBB testing.  I can envision a 16.04 version of the above ‘Jarrret’ procedure. To that end:

1. Can this success be reproduced with 16.04 (are there any nonstarters)?
2. What changes would be needed to said procedure to install 16.04 on the rPi4?
3. Is there any reason why [Sakaki's boot & modules](https://github.com/sakaki-/bcm2711-kernel/releases/download/4.19.66.20190816/bcm2711-kernel-4.19.66.20190816.tar.xz) can not be used to develop a working 16.04-rpi4 image install?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the kernel autobuild cited in your question (sakaki) and can see no reason it shouldn't also work for 16.04 on an RPi4B (at least for console boot; you'll need an appropriate version of mesa to fully leverage the RPi4's graphics capability etc.)

PS the:

```
enable_gic=1
```

line in `(/boot/)config.txt` is redundant with modern kernels and can safely be omitted.

Any questions feel free to email me (sakaki@deciban.com).

Good luck ^-^

S.